# Wordpress Using Ajax Jquery to reference custom post thumbnail

Tags: php, jquery

Ok, so I am basically trying to populate a form with a featured image from a custom post type based on the input of the form field (in this case - the slug for the custom post type). I can't seem to get around the 500 internal server error when I try to access the db from the external PHP script I'm using with the $wpdb class.

Here's my javascript:

```
function updatePrevImage(did){
    jQuery("form .form-designdetails-front div#design-preview").html("Put Animated .gif here").show();
    var thumbquery="/scripts/getdesignprev.php";
    jQuery.post(thumbquery,{designID:did},function(data){
        jQuery("form .form-designdetails-front div#design-preview").html(data).show();
    });
}


jQuery("#field_g6zk24").change(function(did){
    var did=jQuery("#field_g6zk24").val();
    updatePrevImage(did);
});
```

I'm quite certain I have the jQuery written properly. It's the PHP that's the problem I think.

```
<?php  
// get the design slug from the form field
    //$designID=$_POST['designID'];
    require_once('../wp-blog-header.php');
    $designID=$_POST['designID'];
    //$designID="SEN-125-15";
    // get the slug from the custom field
if ( '' != $designID ) {
    //get the post id from the custom field slug
    global $wpdb;
    $my_id = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_type='designs' AND post_name = %s",$designID));
    /*$args = array('name' => $designID, 'post_type' => 'designs');
    $loop = new WP_Query($args);
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
            the_post_thumbnail();
        endwhile;*/
    //echo $designID;
    // display the post thumbnail.
    $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($my_id) );
    echo $url;
}
?>
```

You can see the for page here: 
http://www.highschoolimpressions.com/order-form/?design_number=SEN-125-15
The window I am trying to populate the image in is down in the "Front" section. For right now I am just trying to get the url for the image to populate in there, but I can't even get that. I understand the jQuery still needs to be modified to actually display the image.

Any help would be much appreciated here. I'm at a roadblock here.